# Animation don't work with a changing of the ImageView Drawable

Tags: java, android, xml, android-animation

Hi have a problem with Animation, actually i want to fade my ImageView while it's changing it resource.
It's not working, i can change the resource but without any animation.

```
private void checkX() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (x) {
    case (1): {
        startingAnimation();
        xImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.test_uno);
        endingAnimation();
        break;
    }
    case (2): {
        startingAnimation();
        xImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.test_due);
        endingAnimation();
        break;
    }
    case (3): {
        startingAnimation();
        xImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.test_tre);
        endingAnimation();
        break;
    }
    case (4): {
        startingAnimation();
        xImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.test_quattro);
        endingAnimation();
        break;
    }
    case (5): {
        x = 1;
        checkX();
        break;
    }
    case (0): {
        x = 4;
        checkX();
        break;
    }
    }
}


private void endingAnimation() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ObjectAnimator animation2 = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(xImg, "alpha", 255);
    animation2.setDuration(1000);
    animation2.start();

}

private void startingAnimation() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(xImg, "alpha", 0);
    animation.setDuration(1000);
    animation.start();
}
```

checkX is called each time i press a button(that add or subtract 1 to X).

How i can make both animations and ImageView resource change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the image source when the animation's **onAnimationEnd** is called. For example:

```
animation.addListener(new AnimatorListener() {

    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) { }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) { }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
        // change your ImageView's source here
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) { }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply fade out animation on your ImageView and set animationListener to it. on animation end change your views resource and set fade in animation on it

For fade in animation

```
Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
            fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); 
            fadeIn.setDuration(1000);
            final AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false); 
            animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
```

For fade out animation

```
Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
                fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); 
                fadeOut.setDuration(300);
                final AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false);
                animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
```

Thats how you implement listner on animation

```
fadeout.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener(){

            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation arg0) {
            }           

            @Override 
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation arg0) {
            }           

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation arg0) {
                //change resource of Imageview here             
            }
        });
```

Comment: you can accept the answer if it was helpfull..Glad to help out! chears